# Ngrx: How to monitor a single object in array for change

Tags: angular, ngrx

This is how I am monitoring a `selectedUser` in array. However, if any other element of the array is updated the `watchSelectedUser` observable is triggered where as it should only be triggered on the update to `selectedUser` object.

--- Current code ---

**Reducer Code:**

```
export const userAdapter = createEntityAdapter<UserModel>({
  selectId: x => x.UserId
});
export interface UserlistState extends EntityState<UserModel>{
  selectedUserId: number
};

export const initialState: UserlistState = userAdapter.getInitialState({
  selectedUserId: undefined,
}); 

const getSelectedUserIdState = (state) => { 
  return state.userlist.selectedUserId
};
export const getSelectedUserId = createSelector(getSelectedUserIdState,userId => userId);
```

**Subscribing to a selectedUser model change**

```
watchSelectedUser = (): Observable<UserModel>=>{
        return this.userlistStore.select(userlistReducers.selectAll).pipe(map(users => {
            return users.find(x=> x.UserId == this.getSelectedUserId());
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting your data structure from an array into a collection / key-value pair for each user.

This will allow you to `select(userlistReducers[_id])` and means that you will not have other `UserModel` objects altering an array that they are contained within.

```
state: ApplicationState = {
   users: {
      'd27f23d67f23i7d23': {name: 'Nate, '_id': 'd27f23d67f23i7d23'},
      '87387387g3487gd83': {name: 'Shyamal, '_id': '87387387g3487gd83'}
   }
}


watchSelectedUser = (): Observable <UserModel> => {
    return this.userlistStore.select(userReducers['87387387g3487gd83']);
}
```

This is a bit crude and I'm not sure if the `select()` logic is perfect, but you can now access just one user at a time. It will require a bit of refactor and a new entity adapter, but it is IMO a better structure.

Comment: Can you share an example please

Comment: check out my example

Comment: No I also need another variable in state ie. `selectedId`. How to monitor `selectedUser` with `selectedId`

Comment: No I also need another variable in state ie. `selectedId`. How to monitor `selectedUser` with `selectedId`

Comment: in my example I hard coded the selectedID, you can replace with a variable `userReducers[selectedId]`

Comment: It's tough to advise with seeing the interface for your AppState